# Trying to enhance a custom textbox in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a custom textbox directive. The directive has a input element inside.

I'm trying to make attribute directives to enhance it via:

1) not allow a user to type over 'n' number of characters at which point, I'll probably call a callback function to alert them. Note that this should also work when the user pastes characters into the textbox.

I know html provides the maxlength property but I don't have access to the input box, and I also want to fire a callback when the limit is reached what that doesn't provide.

This is what I tried so far in the link function:

```
element.on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (model.length > n) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //call some passed in callback function here.
    }
});

element.on('paste', function(event) {
    //do something similar here (but having trouble modifying the input from
    //the paste event) I want to strip out characters if it goes over the limit
});
```

I don't know if there's a better way to do this: maybe via ngModelOptions?

I know there's also a ngMaxLength, but I'm not sure if that will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parsers and formatters to custom validate the input data fields
 Pls refer :
 https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/
 for deep insights.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])

.directive('mydiv', function() {
return  {
restrict : 'E',
template : '<input ng-model = "name" custom type = "text"/>'
}
})
.directive('custom' , function(){
return {
  restrict : 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope , ele , attrs, ngModel){
      
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(view , model){
        if(view.length > 5){
           alert('Value should not be more than 5 characters.');
            var val = view.substr(0,5);
            ngModel.$viewValue = val;
            ngModel.$render();
             return val;
            
        }else{
         return view;
        }
        
      })
    }
}


});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app = 'myApp'>
  Hello, {{name}}! <br/><br/>
  <mydiv></mydiv>
</div>
```